# jq search and replace a block "[]" inside of a json file

Tags: jq

I need to remove `run_list` values between `[]` and replace them with a variable I define in `a`.

RUNLIST:

```
{
  "name": "blah200.blah.stage.blahblah.com",
  "chef_environment": "blahenv",
  "run_list": [
  "recipe[blah1]",
  "recipe[blah2]",
  "recipe[blah3]",
  "recipe[blah4]",
  "recipe[blah5]",
  "recipe[blah6]",
  "recipe[blah7]",
  "recipe[blah8]",
  "recipe[blah9]"
]
,
  "normal": {
    "tags": [
      "run_once"
    ],
    "selinux": {
      "status": "disabled"
    },
    "blah_pkger": {
      "access": {
        "blah": "x.x.x.x"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
a="[ recipe[blah11], recipe[blah12], recipe[blah12], recipe[blah13], recipe[blah14], recipe[blah15], recipe[blah16], recipe[blah17], recipe[blah18], recipe[blah19], recipe[blah20], recipe[blah21], recipe[blah22], recipe[blah23] ]"
```

I know I can do something like

```bash
jq --args newval $a '(.run_list[]| select(.run_list))|= $newval' file.json > tmp.json
```

but it is failing giving me this error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your new array elements in a shell array like so:

```bash
a=(
        'recipe[blah11]' 'recipe[blah12]' 'recipe[blah12]' 'recipe[blah13]'
        'recipe[blah14]' 'recipe[blah15]' 'recipe[blah16]' 'recipe[blah17]'
        'recipe[blah18]' 'recipe[blah19]' 'recipe[blah20]' 'recipe[blah21]'
        'recipe[blah22]' 'recipe[blah23]'
)
```

Then you may replace the `run_list` array with these elements like so:

```bash
jq '.run_list = $ARGS.positional' file --args "${a[@]}"
```

... where your document is stored in `file`.

The `--args` option must be the last option on the command line of `jq`, and the array is expanded into individually quoted strings after it.  Inside the `jq` expression, those strings are available as the array `$ARGS.positional`, and we simply assign this array to the correct place in the document.

If you have the new values as a valid JSON array in a scalar shell variable,

```bash
a='[
  "recipe[blah11]", "recipe[blah12]", "recipe[blah12]", "recipe[blah13]",
  "recipe[blah14]", "recipe[blah15]", "recipe[blah16]", "recipe[blah17]",
  "recipe[blah18]", "recipe[blah19]", "recipe[blah20]", "recipe[blah21]",
  "recipe[blah22]", "recipe[blah23]"
]'
```

Then you could do

```bash
jq --argjson value "$a" '.run_list = $value' file
```

Note that you will have to use `--argjson` here as you want `jq` to use `$a` as a JSON document fragment, not to encode the value as a string.